# How to test that a vue component has rendered after a pinia state change?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils, pinia, vitest

I'm trying to write a unit test which checks whether a component has rendered when the pinia state has changed.

I would expect that `store.menuIsActive = true` would mean that `expect(toolbar.exists()).toBe(true)` passes, but it is failing.

```
// LayoutToggleToolbar.vue
<script setup lang="ts">
import { useLayoutStore } from '../store';
import type { Page } from '@/layouts/default.vue';

const props = defineProps<{
  items: Page[];
}>();

const store = useLayoutStore();
</script>

<template>
  <div class="toggle-toolbar">
    <Transition name="toolbar">
      <BaseNavToolbar
        v-if="store.menuIsActive"
        class="toggle-toolbar__items"
      >
        <BaseNavToolbarList class="toggle-toolbar__items__pages">
          <BaseNavToolbarItem v-for="item in props.items">
            <RouterLink to="/">{{ item.text }}</RouterLink>
          </BaseNavToolbarItem>
        </BaseNavToolbarList>
      </BaseNavToolbar>
    </Transition>
  </div>
</template>
```

```
// test.spec.ts
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import { describe, it, expect } from 'vitest';
import { createTestingPinia } from '@pinia/testing';
import { useLayoutStore } from '../store';

import LayoutToggleToolbar from './index.vue';
import BaseNavToolbar from '@/components/base/nav/toolbar/index.vue';

describe('LayoutToggleToolbar', () => {
  const items = [{ text: 'Page 1' }, { text: 'Page 2' }, { text: 'Page 3' }];

  const testPinia = createTestingPinia({
    initialState: { menuIsActive: false }
  });

  const wrapper = mount(LayoutToggleToolbar as any, {
    props: { items },
    global: {
      plugins: [testPinia],
      components: { BaseNavToolbar }
    }
  });

  const store = useLayoutStore();

  it('displays the toolbar when menuIsActive is true', () => {
    const toolbar = wrapper.findComponent(BaseNavToolbar);
    expect(toolbar.exists()).toBe(false);

    store.menuIsActive = true;
    expect(toolbar.exists()).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: wrapper.findComponent isn't supposed to be reactive, you need to do a query again

Comment: import { createTestingPinia } from '@pinia/testing'; createTestingPinia is not identified from @pini/testing. Any help on this like which package do I need to install and other?

Answer (score 0):

You can test like this.

```
describe('LayoutToggleToolbar', () => {
  ...

  it('Render the component without error.', () => {
    store.menuIsActive = true;
    expect(wrapper.isVueInstance()).toBeTruthy()
  })
})
```

Comment: Testing that true === true doesn't have much value

Comment: Edited, could you test again please?

Comment: I mean that ` expect(store.menuIsActive).toBeTruthy()` test efficiently tests the previous line, not the unit (vue component)

Comment: I understood the question and your message @EstusFlask . It wouldn't be the case of just setting true in the store and checking the instance if it exists and testing the opposite too. Edited again.